# Understanding determinants and matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

My question is, looking at a determinant geometrically as a 'volume', is dividing by the determinant similar to getting unit values for the elements of a matrix?

Comment: Are you talking about dividing a matrix by its own determinant, or dividing by the determinant in Cramer's rule?

Comment: Sorry, by its own determinant

Comment: In fact, as the answer below indicates, you should consider dividing by the cube root of the determinant (or, in $n$ dimensional space, the $n$th root).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, let's go over what a determinant is.  Given a linear transformation $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ (determinants are defined on more general spaces, but I can only visualize it geometrically for $\Bbb R^n$) defined by $f(x) = Ax$ for $A \in M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)$, we know that *volumes* (technically **generalized** volumes) in the domain of the $f$ are transformed in a multilinear fashion into volumes in the image of $f$.

For example, let's say we have a linear transformation $f: \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$.  Then, if we know that the volume of the parallelotope with sides $v_1$, $v_2$, and $v_3$ (where $v_1, v_2, v_3 \in \Bbb R^3$) is 12, then we can be sure that the volume of the parallelotope with sides $f(v_1)$, $f(v_2)$, and $f(v_3)$ is $\det(f)\cdot 12$, where $\det(f) := \det(A)$.

---

Dividing a matrix by its determinant is tantamount to defining a new function $f^*$ given by $f^*(x) = \left(\frac 1{\det(A)}A\right)x$.  But remember that $$\det(kA) = k^n\det(A)$$ where $k$ is a constant and $A$ is $n\times n$.  Thus this new transformation $f^*$ doesn't keep volumes the same (unless $\det(A)=1$) -- it transforms volumes by $$\det(f^*) = \det\left(\frac 1{\det(A)}A\right) = \frac{1}{\det(A)^n}\det(A) = \frac{1}{\det(A)^{n-1}}$$

So I think what you really wanted to do is ask about dividing a matrix by $\det(A)^{1/n}$.  Confirm for yourself that the determinant of the matrix $\frac{1}{\det(A)^{1/n}}A$ (assuming $\det(A) \ne 0$) is $1$.

---

Okay.  What does that mean geometrically?  It means that the transformation $g^*$ given by $g^*(x) = \frac{1}{\det(B)^{1/n}}Bx$ *doesn't change volumes* of parallelotopes at all.

And what does that mean for the columns of this matrix $\frac{1}{\det(B)^{1/n}}B$?  Well remember that the columns are just $g^*(e_1)$, $g^*(e_2)$, etc. (where $\{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$ are the standard basis for $\Bbb R^n$). What it **doesn't** mean is that each one of those vectors is unit-length.  Remember if we have the vectors $(1,1)$ and $(2,3)$, then the area of the parallelogram of those two vectors is $1$.  But of course, neither $(1,1)$ nor $(2,3)$ have unit lengths.

So all scaling the matrix does is scale the lengths of the image vectors *proportionally* so that they preserve volumes from the domain of the transformation.

Comment: Thanks for being so thorough. What I was actually doing in my head was dividing the elements by the determinant() and then factoring out the determinant when multiplying the vectors together again and not cubing the determinant in the denominator like I should have (you cover this in your response). Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

First, the determinant, geometrically, as a volume is only true for a 3 by 3 determinant.  In that case, we can think of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 4\end{bmatrix}$ as made from the three vectors <2, 0, 0>, <0, 3, 0>, and <0, 0, 4> which form sides of a rectangle with sides of length 2, 3, and 4, lying along the three axes so of volume $abc= 2(3)(4)= 24$.  Dividing the matrix by 24, we get $\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{12} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{8} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6}\end{bmatrix}$ which has determinant $\frac{1}{56}$ NOT 1.

Comment: The determinant is always a *generalized* volume.  E.g. a $2\times 2$ determinant represents area and a $4\times 4$ determinant represents $4$-volume.